# Verb play vs Present participle playing

Tags: grammar, verbs

There are two boys [] in the park. I was given a question to fill in the blanks. I assume the answer is playing.

But in what context should I be using present tense of the verb vs present participle?

Ans 1: play
Ans 2: playing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the [present simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/talking-about-present) to talk about things that happen regularly, habitually, continually or things that are generally true

> The two boys play in the park every saturday - regularly
>
> The two boys usually play in the park - habitually
>
> These two boys play in the village football team - continually
>
> Boys play football - generally true

The continually and generally true usages don't work very well with play- see the link for better examples.

Compare that with **are playing**, which implies some continuous action that is taking place now:

> There are two boys playing in the park

This means that, right now, two boys are in the park: they have been playing for a while, and it seems likely that they will continue to do so for a while.